# How to do a loop to sort and update list<> based on specific condition

Tags: c#, linq, list, 3d

I have a list of 3D data inside a list namely `c_Top`

The `c_Top` list consist of a pattern where it orders the y value in descending order and it was something like below:

```
//[ x,  y, z]      
  [ 2, 10, 1] //c_Top[0]
  [ 7,  8, 1] //c_Top[1]
  [ 1,  7, 2] //c_Top[2]
  [ 3,  6, 1] //c_Top[3]
  [ 4,  6, 2] //c_Top[4]
  .               .   
  .               . 
  .           //c_Top[cTop.Count - 1]
```

**Now, my objective is to get all the x value inside c_Top list based on the condition where it has the same z value**

```
for (int i = 0; i < c_Top.Count; i++)
{
    if (i != c_Top.Count - 1)
    {
        // if the next data and the current data has same z, then proceed
        if (c_Top[i].p.Z == c_Top[i + 1].p.Z)
        {
            // if the x of next data is greater than current x of current data
            if (c_Top[i + 1].p.X > c_Top[i].p.X)
            {
                // Select all the x and y value at X+ direction
                xy_xplusList = c_Top.Select(x => x.p.X).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
            }

            // if the x of next data is smaller than current x of current data
            else if (c_Top[i + 1].p.X < c_Top[i].p.X)
            {
                // Select all the x and y value at X- direction
                xy_xminusList = c_Top.Select(x => x.p.X).OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
            }
        }

        if (xy_xplusList.Count > 0)
        {
              //Do something
        }

        if (xy_xminusList.Count > 0)
        {
              //Do something
        }
}
```

I am using the above for loop, and the above data example. Due to the reason of `c_Top[1]` and `c_Top[2]` has different value of z. Therefore, when `i = 1`, `the c_Top[1].p.X` is not saved even it has the same z as in `c_Top[0]`

I get the result like this

```
//Output
xy_xplusList  =  { 2 } //only one x values from  c_Top[0] is saved
xy_xminusList =  { 0 }
```

But actually the result I want is like this when

```
c_Top[0] // Output xy_xplusList = { 2, 3 } 
         //       xy_xminusList = { 0 }

c_Top[1] // Output xy_xplusList = { 0 }
         //       xy_xminusList = { 3 }

c_Top[2] // Output xy_xplusList  = { 1 , 4 }
         //        xy_xminusList = { 0 }

c_Top[3] // Ouput xy_xplusList  = { 7 }
         //       xy_xminusList = { 2 }

c_Top[4] // Ouput xy_xplusList  = { 0 }
         //       xy_xminusList = { 1 }
```

In short. I want to consider each of the data inside `c_Top` list.

when considering `c_Top[i]`:

If all of the data of z value inside `c_Top` list has the same z as `c_Top[i].p.Z`, then it will check all the x value inside the `c_Top` list.

If got x value greater than `c_Top[i].p.X`, then the x will be added into `xy_xplusList`

If got x value smaller than `c_Top[i].p.X`, then the x will be added into `xy_minusList`

Is there some LINQ way on doing it?

Something like after I sort with same z, check all the x inside the list, and add to `xy_xplusList`

**Explanation Update**

In each of the coordinate in list, first I check they are at the same Z field or not. If they are same Z field, then I check all the X.

If X is greater than the current x coordinate, then add the x to xplusList

If X is smaller than the current x coordinate, then add the x to xminusList

*I repeat the above process for all of the coordinate inside the list.

**Explanation Update2**

[image]
[image]
Imaging that the tip of the pyramid polygon above is the one coordinate in c_Top list

To draw the pyramid polygon, we need the coordinate of TIP, the coordinate of RHS from the tip and the coordinate of LHS from the tip, the coordinate of the FRONT, and the coordinate from the back.

So, Now, back to the question. I have stored multiple TIP coordinate inside the c_Top list. Now I want to check for all the coordinates in RHS from the tip (in +X direction) and also the LHS from the tip (in -X direction). And the same for FRONT and BACK coordinates.

Imaging that I have multiple TIP coordinate arranged in the same Z field with different height. I want to connected all of the tip together with respect to the highest tip coordinate as show the pink color line below:
[image]

**Update: Answer the question by myself and this question shall be closed**

```
//Group all the Z coordinate throughout the v_Tip list
var groupedZ = from p in v_Tip
               group p by p.p.Z into q
               select q;

foreach (var groupZ in groupedZ)
{
    //Order the groupZ with Y coordinate descending order
    var SameZList = groupZ.OrderByDescending(y => y.p.Y).ThenBy(x => x.p.X).ToList();

    //Since the list is order by descending w.r.t Y coordinate, the SameZList[0] will be the peak coordinate in groupZ
    var peakZ = SameZList[0];

    // At same Z, mean at XY plane
    for (int i = 1; i < SameZList.Count; i++)
    {
        // mean the x is at the RHS from the peak
        if (peakZ.p.X < SameZList[i].p.X)
        {
            // add all the X and Y coordinates in RHS direction from the peak (X+ direction from the peak
            xy_xplusList.Add(SameZList[i].p.X);
            xy_yplusList.Add(SameZList[i].p.Y);
        }
        else // the x is at the LHS from the peak
        {
            // add all the X and Y coordinates in LHS direction from the peak (X- direction from the peak
            xy_xminusList.Add(SameZList[i].p.X);
            xy_yminusList.Add(SameZList[i].p.Y);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not following your question. are you asking for a subset of the list where the same value is in the X and Z fields?

Comment: I feel difficulty to carry the question clearly too.. In the same Z filed, I want to check all the X, weather it is greater than the current X or smaller than the current X. I will edit and update the question when I think of the proper way of explaining it.

Comment: Can you talk a little bit about your goal, in terms or result, rather than solution, in the hope it will clarify the problem?

Comment: @Michael I updated my goal inside the question. :)

Comment: Do you want to order all coordinates with the same Z by their Y coordinates?

Comment: no need. I am considering all the Y coordinates in the same Z. In the last picture, tip[0], tip[1], tip[2], tip[4] are same Z, hence they connect the point together.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i'm 100% on your question... but how's this work for you?

```
    public void DoWork(List<int[]> c_Top)
    {
        var distinctZvalues = c_Top.Select(p => p[2]); // this gets an enumerable object of unique Z values

        List<int[]> xy_minus = new List<int[]>();
        List<int[]> xy_plus = new List<int[]>();

        foreach (var z in distinctZvalues)
        {
            List<int[]> coords = c_Top.Where(p => p[2] == z).ToList(); // pull all int[] from c_Top where z == z
            foreach (int[] coord in coords)
                if (coord[0] > coord[1])
                    xy_minus.Add(coord);
                else
                    xy_plus.Add(coord);
        }
    }
```

Or, after further review, you might be looking for unique lists based on Z value...

```
public void DoWork2(List<int[]> c_Top)
    {
        var distinctZvalues = c_Top.Select(p => p[2]); // this gets an enumerable object of unique Z values

        Dictionary<int, List<int[]>> xy_minus = new Dictionary<int, List<int[]>>();
        Dictionary<int, List<int[]>> xy_plus = new Dictionary<int, List<int[]>>();

        foreach (var z in distinctZvalues)
        {
            List<int[]> minus = new List<int[]>();
            List<int[]> plus = new List<int[]>();
            List<int[]> coords = c_Top.Where(p => p[2] == z).ToList(); // pull all int[] from c_Top where z == z
            foreach (int[] coord in coords)
                if (coord[0] > coord[1])
                    minus.Add(coord);
                else
                    plus.Add(coord);
            xy_minus.Add(z, minus);
            xy_plus.Add(z, plus);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i havent misunderstood your question

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int[]> c_top=new List<int[]>();
        c_top.Add(new int[3]{ 2, 10, 1});
        c_top.Add(new int[3]{ 7,  8, 1});
        c_top.Add(new int[3]{ 2,  7, 2});
        c_top.Add(new int[3]{ 3,  6, 1});
        c_top.Add(new int[3]{  4,  6, 2});

        var result=c_top.Where(x => x[0] == x[2]).Select(s => s[0]).ToList();
    }
}
```